# Как отключить шумоподавление микрофона на iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin

Возможно ли отключить шумоподавление микрофона программными средствами? После некорректной замены шлейфа при разговоре стал проявляться эффект "бочки", шумоподавление работает некорректно из-за резонанса с металлическим корпусом. Если возможно, хочу попробовать это исправить на уровне оси.

**Модель:** iPhone 5S
**Версия:** iOS 9.3.2

p.s. я знаю что это не выход, но как временная мера вполне подойдет.

Comment: Тем кто минусует - где аргументы? Вы сами то хотябы разбираетесь в теме вопроса? А то опять набежит толпа линуксоидов, и начинает тему с iOS закрывать!

Comment: в IOS изменение настроек ядра/железа приложениям не доступно. И не будет доступно никогда. Вопрос можете снимать.

Comment: @iosp, понятно, спасибо. Тоже самое что и в WinPhone 8.1. Жаль, опубликуйте это как ответ.

Comment: @All голосуйте за закрытие вопроса, а не тупо ставьте минусы.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не имеет отношения к программированию

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, что в определении "программными средствами" наталкивает на мысль "без программирования"? Вопрос про программирование данного функционала был.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, звук при телефонном разговоре в iOS фильтруется программными средствами. Вопрос был в том - как отключить эти фильтры именно в телефонном разговоре, потому что из-за "хреновой" починки телефона на шлейф забыли надеть шумопоглощающие накладки, вследствии чего фильтрация звука работает некорректно (проявляется эффект бочки) из-за резонанса корпуса.

Comment: может проще в ремонт сходить, чем нас тут всех слюной забрызгивать.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, Вы сами то себя слышите? Вы - программист! Вопрос - по программированию! А вы отправляете "легче и проще" - в сервисный центр. Да и перечитайте вопрос, в p.s. я уже сказал по этому поводу.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, по поводу слюны, как Вы выразились - я услышал только один толковый ответ, его и принял. Все остальное - вообще в другую степь ведет. Конкретный вопрос - должен быть конкретный ответ, а эта "вода" в комментах никому не нужна. Вам будет приятно если левые люди, большинство из которых даже не разбираются в iOS - ставят вашему вопросу минусы, хотя вопрос корректен?

Comment: зачем Вы хотите вот это: *потому что из-за "хреновой" починки телефона на шлейф забыли надеть шумопоглощающие накладки, вследствии чего фильтрация звука работает некорректно (проявляется эффект бочки) из-за резонанса корпуса.* исправить программно? если ремонт не качественный, то пусть ремонтники исправляют свои *косяки*

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что потому что это попытка исправить физический дефект программными средствами

Comment: @Bald))) что-то я не видел в причинах закрытия вопросов: "потому что это попытка исправить физический дефект программными средствами"

Comment: это кастомная причина, Закрытие->Не по теме->*{Помоему последний вариант}*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В iOS изменение настроек ядра/железа приложениям не доступно. И не будет доступно никогда. Вопрос можете снимать

Comment: ну прям никогда? откуда уверенность? :)

Comment: Шанс на обратное ничтожен, можно и пованговать.

Answer (score 0):

> Настройки → Основные → Универсальный доступ → Шумоподавление телефона

А минусует за то, что не связано с тематикой ruSO.

Comment: А Вы уверены что это именно то что нужно? Насколько мне известно Шумоподавление телефона в настройках отвечает только за звук со стороны собеседника.

Comment: И каким же это макаром не связано с тематикой ruSO? Все тут связано, программные средства iOS, iOS-SDK. Вопрос корректен, а минусы - необоснованы.

Comment: Так же метки вопроса указаны верно, причем все 4 метки. Эти языки и обертки (xamarin, если можно так выразиться) - напрямую связаны с iOS.

Comment: @Align не надо злиться, вопрос действительно не имеет отношения к тематике СО - поскольку вы НЕ просите помощи в программировании/системном администрировании. Если бы например вопрос был, хочу сделать свое voip приложение и в нем подавлять шумы, тогда бы был разговор. по той же причине метки objc, swift и xamarin тут не нужны, раз вы сами говорите, что хотите исправить на уровне оси.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, перечитайте вопрос. Я просил помощи именно в программировании, язык в данном случае не имеет значения, реализовать можно на любом, это не так сложно. Если бы ядро iOS не было защищено (так же как и у WinPhone 8.1) - то в ответ просто кинули ссылку на метод в SDK либо пример программной реализации на любом из языков. Вот и все. Нужно просто вчитаться в вопрос. Вопрос напрямую относится к программированию.